# How do browsers calculate block width if first-line has different font-size?

Tags: html, css

Here is a short example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Foo</title>
  <style>
    .container {
      width: fit-content;
      white-space: pre-line;
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    
    .container:first-line {
      font-size: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you open it in your browser, you'll notice that `div` is significantly wider than the text inside of it (I tried Chrome 90.0.4430.85). If you set `.container`'s `font-size` to same value as `.container:first-line`, `div`'s width will perfectly fit the text width.

I didn't found any spec describing that behavior, but it seems that if `font-size` of the `first-line` differs form `font-size` of other lines, block width is calculated assuming that all have the same `font-size` and this `font-size` is the biggest one in this block. This why `div` was wider than needed, it's width was calculated as if it's second line `font-size` was `20px` while it was `14px`.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, and tell me if there are any ways to make this `div` fit its text if `font-size`s are different.

Comment: this is probably a bug. Can you put the first line into a <span>?

Comment: Yes, wrapping first line into a <span> with explicit styles solves the problem, but it's still unclear why :first-line styling doesn't work